# Usando Data Annotations para validar campos de uma página HTML e Web API

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-web-api

Alguém tem um exemplo de como criar uma validação de campos em uma página de HTML usando Data Annotation, Web API e C#.

No MVC consigo, isso se consegue facilmente usando Wizard ao criar uma View.

Comment: entenda que ao usar WebApi você irá trabalhar apenas com recebimento e envio de json, a validação do DataAnnotation é válida, pois o MVC é quem rendeniza os seus inputs, no caso da WebApi, o mais interessante, seria você retornar um JSON com os erros que estarão no ModelState e aí você envia-los pela View

Comment: Ah, só um detalhe, você PODE usar data annotation sim, não interprete mal, entretanto é como eu expliquei acima =)

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente o DataAnnotation são as propriedades que ficam em cima dos campos de sua model

ex:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "User name")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "E-mail em formato inválido.")]
```

Um artigo simples e direto:
http://eduardopires.net.br/2013/04/mvc-validando-dados-com-dataannotations/